# Translate object until collision

Tags: c#, game-physics, unity-game-engine

I want my object to keep moving in the target's direction forever or until it collides, the collision part I have already handled it; However, I am having problems with the movement part.

I first try to rotate my target using these lines of code

```
Vector2 diff = target - transform.position;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, angle);
```

This works perfect and my object rotates in the direction I want it to.
In my Update method I have the following

```
if (isMoving)
    {
        Vector2 f = transform.forward;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target + Vector3.forward, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Now this runs but fails to accomplish the goal and I know why, it makes sense but not sure how to fix it. The object moves to the point in the correct direction but I don't want it to stop at the target, I want it to keep going.

I also tried

```
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + f * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

rb is a rigidbody2D

as well as

```
rb.AddForce(rb.position + f * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

But in both cases the object rotates but never moves

I also used translate and same behavior as MovePosition

P.S. It's a 2D game

Comment: Post the complete code including update, collision triggers etc...

Comment: @Isma Thank you, I was able to solve it by using the line equation. I answered my question if you want to take a look at the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking over the internet, I didn't find anything that really does what I am looking for, you are not able to translate a kinematic object forever (Obviously you have to handle that the object should get destroyed at some point or something, but that's not the issue). So I went ahead and decided to write my own library to make this simple. I was able to achieve my goal using the line equation. Simple I took these steps to solve my issue.

1. At start I get the slope between 2 points
2. Calculate the y-intercept
3. translate the object using the line equation with a fixed X value (step), every x value find the corresponding y value and translate the object to it.
4. Repeat step 3 in a FixedUpdate and that's it.

Of course there is more to it, handling cases where x = 0 which will give a 0 division for the slope or y = 0, etc... I solved all of that in the library. For anyone interested you can check it out here [EasyMovement](https://github.com/Muhand/EasyMovement)

If you don't want the library then here is a simple code that will do it.

```
 //Start by Defining 5 variables
 private float slope;
 private float yintercept;
 private float nextY;
 private float nextX;
 private float step;
 private Vector3 direction;    //This is your direction position, can be anything (e.g. a mouse click)
```

In the **Start** Method

```
//step can be anything you want, how many steps you want your object to take, I prefer 0.5f
step = 0.5f;

//Calculate Slope => (y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
slope = (gameObject.transform.position.y - direction.y) / (gameObject.transform.position.x - direction.x);

//Calculate Y Intercept => y1-x1*m
yintercept = gameObject.transform.position.y - (gameObject.transform.position.x * slope);
```

Now in **FixedUpdate**

```
//Start by calculating the nextX value
//nextX
if (direction.x > 0)
    nextX = gameObject.transform.position.x + step;
else
    nextX = gameObject.transform.position.x - step;

//Now calcuate nextY by plugging everything into a line equation
nextY = (slope * nextX) + yintercept;

//Finally move your object into the new coordinates
gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(gameObject.transform.position, new Vector3(nextX, nextY, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Keep in mind this won't do the heavy lifting, there are a lot of conditions that needs to be taken into consideration.